# Projective Geometry Interpretation In combinatorics

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

Find the maximum number of subsets that satisfy this trait

~ Each Subset has 4 element

~ Each two subset share 2 elements in common

~ There can't be more than 1 number that are included in all subsets

I wanted to transform this into a projective geometry approach by taking each subset as a cyclic quadrilateral and each intersection as a 2 of the  point in each cyclic Quadri

Link That Motivates
(https://brilliant.org/wiki/projective-geometry/)

could someone here give a hint or help me solve this
with using any method

Comment: "Each intersection of subset is 2" $\to$ "Each intersection of subset has 2 elements", isn't it ? Besides, the sentence "meaning if we have $(S_1,...,S_n)$" is not finished.

Comment: Yup correct @JeanMarie (They Have 2 element in common for each subset)  and Lastly the full sentence from the $(S_1,....,S_n)  is that there is no elements that appear in each of the n sets

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience @JeanMarie

Comment: Please incorporate these changes into your question.

Comment: Besides, your sentence " there is no elements that appear in each of the n sets" still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hmm Let me give an example suppose we have 3 subset 
(1,2,3,10) , (1,2,4,11),(1,2,5,16) see here (1,2) appear in each 3 set so it is wrong @JeanMarie

Answer (score 1):

I haven't be able to visualize the reference you give because one has to be a member of such and such for that.

Nevertheless, one can exhibit a solution complying with the different constraints ; take the set of 4 elements subsets of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ which are :

$$\begin{cases}
\{0,1,2,6\}\\
\{0,1,4,5\}\\
\{0,2,3,5\}\\
\{0,3,4,6\}\\
\end{cases}$$
represented here (please note that vertices 5 and 6 are represented twice):

[image]

Is it a maximal solution ? In terms of the number of subsets (as you ask) ? In terms of the total number of elements involved ? It remains an open question.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for your trials but i think this came from past olympiad but i don't know which national olympiad is it

Comment: but i think in subset it is actually already more than 5 consider subset 
{1,2,3,4},{1,2,6,5},{2,6,3,4},{6,4,1,5},{6,5,4,2}

Comment: more than or equal

Comment: No {6,4,1,5},{6,5,4,2} share 3 elements.

Comment: Do you mean that your second condition is "share **at least** two elements" ? In this case, you must add "at least".

Comment: oops my bad but i don't have some concrete proof like double counting using some extremal stuff or even a claim to strengthen this

Comment: but btw here some 5 subset that is correct sorry for the inconvenience before 
(1234)
(1256)
(1278)
(2357)
(1358)